Winforms on .NET 8: why isn't tab index working with user controls?
I'm working with Winforms in .NET 8.0. I've created a number of user controls which work well in every way, except for the tab index.
I've tried setting the tab index at the form level and then at the child level. Nothing seems to work.
Here's an out line of two of my user controls
1.
--UserControl --
colors and bla
*Label* text *Label
--UserControl --




--UserControl--
colors
*Label* text *label* *dropdown*options*dropdown*
--UserControl--

I've tried setting the tab index of the user control and iterating through the child controls to set that. Nothing. The tab buttons doesn't do anything from what I can tell and the enter button the same.
Thanks for whatever help you can give me.



That typically just works. If it doesn't for you there are details involved we can't see here.

I found the issue.  The events of the inner object need to invoke the user controls method.  Then the parents controls will reflect your method.  However, you do have to be aware of the specific event as all do not match.  But you can call a different event to match what you want.
Ex.
'
private void btnOne_PreviewKeyDown(object 
  sender,PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke(this.OnPreviewKeyDown, e);
}

private void btnOne_KeyPress(object sender, v 
 KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke(this.OnKeyPress, e);
}

private void btnOne_MouseClick(object sender,MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke(this.OnMouseClick, e);
}

'

